# Input Tag Helper Not Working with Razor Code

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to combine an input tag helper with razor code to set an attribute but I cannot get the two technologies to work together. I am simply trying to set the disabled attribute on the input field based on the value of view model property.

When i put the razor code after the `asp-for` tag the razor intellisense is not recognized and the field is not disabled as expected...

```
<input asp-for="OtherDrugs" @((Model.OtherDrugs == null) ? "disabled" : "") class="form-control" />
```

Rendered output...

```
<input type="text" id="OtherDrugs" name="OtherDrugs" value="" />
```

When i put the razor code before the `asp-for` tag the tag helper intellisense is not recognized and the field is not set with the view model properties as expected...

```
<input @((Model.OtherDrugs == null) ? "disabled" : "") asp-for="OtherDrug" class="form-control" />
```

Rendered output...

```
<input disabled asp-for="OtherDrugs" class="form-control" />
```

**Note that combining tag helpers and razor does work if the razor code is inside a class attribute. Unfortunately input fields require the disabled attribute and not the disabled class for bootstrap 3.**

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I haven't used TagHelpers so I'm shooting in the dark here, can you wrap the ternary in <text></text>?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To render the disabled input element, you simply need to add a disabled attribute. All the below will render a disabled input text element.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="false" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="no" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="enabled" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="why is it still disabled" />
```

In Asp.NET Core, You can extend the existing input tag helper to create a readonly input tag helper.

Extend the `InputTagHelper` class, add a new property to identify whether the input should be disabled or not and based on this value, add the "disabled" attribute to the input.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class MyCustomTextArea : InputTagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-is-disabled")]
    public bool IsDisabled { set; get; }

    public MyCustomTextArea(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (IsDisabled)
        {
            var d = new TagHelperAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            output.Attributes.Add(d);
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

Now to use this custom textarea helper, you need to call the `addTagHelper` method in `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourAssemblyNameHere
```

Now in your view, you can specify the `asp-is-disabled` attribute value.

```
<input type="text" asp-for="OtherDrugs" 
                                  asp-is-disabled="@Model.OtherDrugs==null"/>
```

Comment: would be nice for it to work out of the box but your custom tag helper did the trick nicely. thanks

Comment: @Shyju I used this custom tag helper for the inputs and it worked nicely except one issue.  It renders a checkbox twice.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: So I can confirm it IS `assembly name - .dll/.exe` extension and not the namespace (sometimes the two might actually differ)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP Core tag helper like this:

```
<input asp-for="Name" />
```

and then put [Editable(false)] for your property like this:

`[Editable(false)]
public string Name {set;get;}`

then you should extend InputTagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class ExtendedInputTagHelper : InputTagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";

    public ExtendedInputTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
        : base(generator) { }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var isContentModified = output.IsContentModified;

        if (For.Metadata.IsReadOnly)
        {
            var attribute = new TagHelperAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            output.Attributes.Add(attribute);
        }

        if (!isContentModified)
        {
            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally import your TagHelper in _ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *, <your assembly name>
```

the advantage of this solution is putting logic in Model and preserving MVC principles.

Answer (score 0):

For me the TagHelper extension is an overkill, since I needed just two inputs disabled/enabled, based on some model values.
Therefore I went for the simpliest (probably not the best) approach - @if/else.

```
@if (Model.OtherDrugs == null)
{
    <input asp-for="OtherDrug" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
}
else
{
    <input asp-for="OtherDrug" class="form-control" />
}
```