# Conditionally render disabled button in asp.net core view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a button in my view which I would like to be disabled based on certain condition. Below is my view:

```
@{
   var myCondition = false;
   myCondition = //set condtion here
}

<input type="submit" value="Create" class=" btn btn-primary" />
```

So based on myCondition I want to disabled/enable my button.

I can do like:

```
 @if(myCondition)
  {
     <input type="submit" value="Create" disabled="disabled" class=" btn btn-primary" />
  }
 else
 {
    //enable it here
 }
```

Is there any elegant way to do that in .net core. Can we use some htmlextensions here. If someone can give me an example pls.

Inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro).

Comment: can I add the tag helper for something like :  <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Action" >Click</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create html helper as:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
        public static IHtmlContent DisabledIf(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                              bool condition)
        => new HtmlString(condition ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "");
}
```

Then in your view:

```
   @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 


<input type="submit" value="Create" class=" btn btn-primary" @Html.DisabledIf(yourcondition) />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not like to conditionally render the button in the view, you can build a  tag helper to do so.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("button")]
public class MyDisablableButton : TagHelper
{      
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-is-disabled")]
    public bool IsDisabled { set; get; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (IsDisabled)
        {
            var d = new TagHelperAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            output.Attributes.Add(d);
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

Now to use this custom tag helper, you need to call the `addTagHelper` method in `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourAssemblyNameHere
```

Now you can use it in views like

```
<button asp-is-disabled="true">Save</button>
<button asp-is-disabled="false">Save</button>
<button asp-is-disabled="@yourBooleanVariable">Save</button>
```

Comment: Where do I check my condition here. Also can I add the tag helper for something like : <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Action" >Click</a>

Comment: you can pass the boolean variable (ex:myCondition )as the value of `asp-is-disabled` attribute. If you want to do the same for anchor tag, you can extend the anchor tag as well. Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487688/asp-net-core-input-tag-helper-not-working-with-razor-code

Comment: Thanks this would work for button. But if I have a link that does not has a disabled property. So how can I add say custom css class that disables it if I use the above code

Comment: See my previous comment. You can extend the anchor tag helper to do so.