# Custom nonvalidation attribute ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, attributes

I know how to create custom validation attribute using `IClientModelValidator` where I can add html attributes using `ClientModelValidationContext`, but how to create an attribute, like `nonwritable` that sets html class with disable to input; it's not good to do it in validation context.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with easier with some tag helper or HTML helper that will render this depending on the condition you pass in.

Example with HTML helper:
[Conditionally render disabled button in asp.net core view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076119/conditionally-render-disabled-button-in-asp-net-core-view)
Example with tag helper:
[Input Tag Helper Not Working with Razor Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487688/input-tag-helper-not-working-with-razor-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="ex" name="example" disabled>
```

When a disabled attribute is present, it specifies that the  element should be disabled. A disabled input element is unusable as well as un-clickable.

The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the  element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the disabled value, and make the  element usable.